# rdiff-backup fails from shell script

Tags: backup, shell, globbing

I am trying to run a shell (sh) script for backups, using rdiff-backup.
The lines of interest are:

```
cmd="${prog} -v5 --print-statistics --include-globbing-filelist ${inclist} \
--exclude ** ${src} ${dest}"
echo "${cmd}"
$cmd
```

It echoes the correct command to me, but chokes on the command itself:

```
rdiff-backup -v5 --print-statistics --include-globbing-filelist /etc/backup/include-list --exclude ** / /backup/all
Using rdiff-backup version 1.2.8
Fatal Error: Switches missing or wrong number of arguments
See the rdiff-backup manual page for more information.
```

Running the command directly does work (using `'**'` instead of `**`). Note that I've tried using `'**'` in the command string, but it's expanded wrong and gives an error like

```
Fatal Error: Fatal Error: The file specification
    ''**'
cannot match any files in the base directory
    '/'
...
```

But I assume this is still an expansion issue, so maybe that's wrong. I am very confused at the moment, and would appreciate some help.

Comment: Add `set -xv` to print out the command as debugging help. Maybe it will help.

Comment: I tried that, actually. It gives me the same string echoed above.

Answer (score 2):

I solved running `bash -c "$cmd"`